# Scala: AnyVal usage

Tags: scala

I am setting a `val` in Scala using an `if` statement, I only want to set the `val` when certain criteria is met and I would like it to be an `Int`. I use/compare the `val` later on with another `Int` which is (currently) always positive:

```
val transpose = if(x < y) 10 else -1
...
if(transpose > min) doSomething
```

I do not like this code because, in the future, `min` may in fact be negative.

I have changed the `if` statement to:

```
val transpose = if(x < y) 10
```

This returns a type `AnyVal`. I am wondering how I can utilise this? I still wish to compare the value held within the `AnyVal` with `min` but only if it is an `Int`, otherwise, I want to continue as if the `if` statement was unsuccessful. In pseudo-code:

```
if(transpose instanceOf(Int) && transpose > min) doSomething
```

I have toyed with using `transpose.getClass` but it just seems like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Make `transpose` optional and if it's a `None` it means it's less than your minimum value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use an `Option`, as suggested by [Ende Neu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1845790/ende-neu):

```
val transpose = if(x < y) Some(10) else None
if(transpose.exists(_ > min)) doSomething
```

Or, just use `Int.MinValue`:

```
val transpose = if(x < y) 10 else Int.MinValue
if(transpose > min) doSomething // won't doSometihng for any "min" if x < y
```

Another good option is to make `transpose` a *function* of type `Int => Boolean` (assuming it's only used for this if statement), thus not needing a type to represent the threshold:

```
val transpose: Int => Boolean = m => if (x < y) 10 > m else false 
if(transpose(min)) doSomething
```

Comment: Instead of `transpose.map(_ > min).getOrElse(false)`, you can just do `transpose.exists(_ > min)`

Comment: Of course - much better, thanks Ben! editing per your suggestion